# how to get matched json from List array in dart (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a json.

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "e_id": 2,
            "e_name": "0",
            "abc": 0,
            "doa": "2021-02-15 13:17:11"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "e_id": 22,
            "e_name": "ok",
            "abc": 1,
            "doa": "2021-02-15 13:17:57"
        }
    ],
    "status": 1,
    "msg": "Successfully fetched"
}
```

and list

```
[2,1,5]
```

i want to add another key to the json where there is matched from the list array

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "e_id": 2,
            "e_name": "0",
            "abc": 0,
            "doa": "2021-02-15 13:17:11",
            "added_key": "added value because the id number 2 is matched from the list array"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "e_id": 22,
            "e_name": "ok",
            "abc": 1,
            "doa": "2021-02-15 13:17:57"
        }
    ],
    "status": 1,
    "msg": "Successfully fetched"
}
```

here is what i have tried

```
List list = [2,1,5];
      for (var i = 0;i < list.length; i++) {
        int aa = data.indexWhere((item) => item["id"] == list[i]);
        data[aa]["added_key"] = "added value";
 }
```

anyone who have any idea how to do that using dart? please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think you need to run loop of the data you are getting. So, it's easy for you to keep track.
What about trying below solution.

```
 data["result"] = data["result"].map((item) {
    final id = item["id"] as int; // Ensure type safety
    if (matchList.contains(id)) {
         // Add the new key with a relevant value
         item["added_key"] = "added value (ID: $id)";
     }
     return item;
  }).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would turn it around and iterate through the results and check if the list contains the id. If the list is long, you could turn it into a set, because a `contains` lookup of a (`HashSet` would be faster than in a `List`)

```
for(final entry in data["result"]) {
    if (list.contains(entry['id'])) {
        entry['added_key'] = 'added value';
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that aa is not -1 before attempting to add `added_key` to the data list. If there is no element that meets the requirement, the `indexWhere` function returns -1.

```
 List<int> list = [2, 1, 5];
    List<dynamic> data = jsonData['result'];

    for (var id in list) {
      int index = data.indexWhere((item) => item["id"] == id);
      if (index != -1) {
        // Check if the ID was found
        data[index]["added_key"] = "added value";
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps!